# Basic Catalan numbers

Tags: python, catalan

I wanna write a program that prints out all Catalan numbers less than or equal to say 100000.

Such are given by `cn=1` and `cn1 = ((4n+2)/n+2)*cn` (next value). When I try it I get the below error.

My code is :

```
 cn,cn1 = 1,2
 n = 1 
 while cn1<100000:
       cn1 = ((4(n+2)/(n+2)))*cn
       print(cn1)
```

My output error:

> runfile('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/cpy/ex_cat_numbe.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/cpy')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/cpy/ex_cat_numbe.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/cpy')
>
> File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/cpy/ex_cat_numbe.py", line 11, in 
>       cn1 = ((4(n+2)/(n+2)))*cn
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: I am trying to replicate the above formula so as to calculate the catalate numbers , with the modified code above I get the error "'int' object is not callable"

Comment: your error is coming from `4(n+2)`; python does not automatically multiply there. Change it to `4 * (n + 2)`

Comment: thanks sean, its only printing 4.0 now though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the correct formula to calculate Catalan number. Here is the code to print Catalan numbers less than or equal to 100000:

```
# A recursive function to find nth catalan number
def catalan(n):
    # Base Case
    if n <= 1:
        return 1

    # Catalan(n) is the sum of catalan(i)*catalan(n-i-1)
    res = 0
    for i in range(n):
        res += catalan(i) * catalan(n - i - 1)

    return res


n = 0
c = catalan(n)
while c <= 100000:
    print(c)
    n += 1
    c = catalan(n)
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
5
14
42
132
429
1430
4862
16796
58786
```

For more information about the code check [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-nth-catalan-number/).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in line 4:

```
cn1 = ((4(n+2)/(n+2)))*cn
```

You should've put a `*` to multiply `4` and `(n+2)`. The way it is, you are trying to call the number 4, the same way you call functions().

But there is a second problem in your code. You are not changing the `cn1` variable inside the while loop. It will always keep the same value.

Try writing the following line after printing your result:

```
cn = cn1
```